# Autofixture and Moq not passing in mocked parameter

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, moq, asp.net-mvc-5, autofixture

I have a parameter passed into a controller like this

```cs
private EnglishForwardLotServiceBase<EnglishForwardLotData, AuctionData, LotFragmentData> englishForwardLotServiceBase;

public EnglishForwardController(
    EnglishForwardLotServiceBase<EnglishForwardLotData, AuctionData, LotFragmentData> englishForwardLotServiceBase)
{
   this.englishForwardLotServiceBase = englishForwardLotServiceBase;
}
```

The definition of `EnglishForwardLotServiceBase` is

```cs
public class EnglishForwardLotServiceBase<LotData, AuctionData, LotFragmentData> : IEnglishForwardLotService<LotData> where AuctionData : PerfectChannel.Services.EnglishForwardLot.IEnglishForwardLotSetup
```

So, in my test I am trying to mock `englishForwardLotServiceBase` like this

```cs
IFixture fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
Mock<IEnglishForwardLotService<EnglishForwardLotData>> englishForwardLotServiceBaseMock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IEnglishForwardLotService<EnglishForwardLotData>>>();
```

The problem is that Autofiture/Moq is not using a mocked version `EnglishForwardLotServiceBase` parameter but the actual implementation.  This is making my tests fail as you can imagine.

What might be the issue?